# Bokeh DoubleTap event: how to find the glyph that was double tapped

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a grid of glyphs generated by `plot.rect` and I want to find the glyph that gets double-tapped by the user. Each glyph represents a datapoint and has 2 associated URLs with it. I'm already using the single-tap action (via TapTool + OpenURL) for the common URL that I want to send the user to, and I wanted to use the double-tap action for a less common URL

Snippet of my code:

```
# self.source contains `logs_link` used below in OpenURL and contains a second
# field called `alt_logs_link` that I want to surface via double-tap.
rect = self.plot.rect(
    x="run_date", y="test_name", width=1, height=1, 
    source=self.source, line_color='#ffffff', line_width=1.5,
    fill_color={'field': 'job_status', 'transform': color_mapper})

taptool = self.plot.select(type=TapTool)
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url="@logs_link{safe}")

def doubletap_callback(event):
    print("IN DOUBLE TAP")
    print(event)
self.plot.on_event(DoubleTap, doubletap_callback)
```

The DoubleTap event only seems to contain x/y coordinates of the event. How can I map these coordinates to the glyph that was double tapped?

Maybe I can use [`.select()` to find the glyph somehow](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#selecting-plot-objects) but I wasn't able to find how to query by x/y coordinates.

I'm open to other suggestions besides double-tap for how to surface 2 different URLs per glyph.